# How to test multi-tenant apps on Heroku staging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

I currently am creating a multi-tenant application using Rails, Heroku and the Apartment gem.  ( Please note I am aware of the limitations of using the multitenant app structure on Heroku for more than 10 different databases ).  I properly set up my application and have the subdomains working properly locally using lvh.me.

Since pushing to XXX-staging.herokuapp.com, the XXX-staging is already a subdomain so it's throwing the error:

```
Apartment::TenantNotFound (One of the following schema(s) is invalid: "XXX-staging" "public"):
```

Is there a way around testing subdomains on Heroku staging environments or is the only way to buy an alternative URL with another SSL wildcard?  I'd prefer if that wasn't what I had to do, since it can be costly.

Comment: Any solution found?

Comment: @uditmittal Yes. We had to make the subdomains point to tenant.staging.XXX.com and skip Heroku all together. Hope that helps.